# ASP.net C# bootstrap datetimepicker assign value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetimepicker

I'm trying to display the date from the code behind in the bootstrap `DateTimePicker`, but it won't display correctly.

This is my HTML/ASP Script:

```
<asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Label">DATE ISSUED:</asp:Label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_DateIssued" runat="server"
                         CssClass="form-control" Width="374px">
            </asp:TextBox>    
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>                    
</asp:TableCell>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' });
    });
</script>
```

And here's my C# code:

```
txt_DateIssued.Text = "2016-03-13";
```

**Output:**
[Output - DateTimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSnJF.png)

and when I clicked on the calendar icon, the year begins at 0003 :(

**QUESTION:**
How can I display the date `2016-03-13` on the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using this control [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). In the future you should include the link to the library you have a question on (if your question is concerning a library).

Your JavaScript looks fine. Are you seeing any console errors in the browser? Are you using the latest version? Here is your code working in a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fp82snL/7/) with the ASP.NET tags converted to standard HTML tags.

Minimal HTML fragment with script tags.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <input type='text' ID="txt_DateIssued" class="form-control" width="374px"></input>    
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. I downloaded again the JQuerry, and now it works fine. :)